# How do I map the root directory to a controller in c# using web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a c# web api (.net 4) web application. I have several controllers. I'd like to map a new controller to the root directory for the web app.

So, I have `http://localhost/listproducts`

I'd like the url to be `http://localhost`

But I don't know how to tell the controller to use the root directory. It seems to be configured based on the name.

The solution I went with is:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "ListProductsApi",
             routeTemplate: "",
             defaults: new { controller = "ListProducts" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

The trick is the `defaults: new { controller = "ListProducts" }`  line. (I need a POST action so I just left action out. Apparently when you want the root route "/" you need to explicitly name the controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply need to change the default route you already have. It should currently look something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Change `controller = "Home"` to `controller = "listproducts"`.

Answer (score 3):

It should be fairly easy, just change a default route in your global.asax.cs and instead of

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

change it to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "ListProducts", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```